# Как реализовать контрастное масштабирование изображения на c# windows forms?

Tags: c#, масштабирование

Задача состоит в том, чтобы реализовать в windows forms загрузку изображения из папки, преобразование в чб и как раз таки контрастное масштабирование черно-белого изображения. Все, что я нахожу в интернете по данной тебе это определение, не дающее мне ровным счетом ничего: с помощью этой функции определенный участок диапазона значений яркости растягивается на всю шкалу

Comment: `я нахожу в интернете по данной тебе это определение, не дающее мне ровным счетом ничего` -- ссылочку на это определение дайте.

Comment: http://computersbooks.net/index.php?id1=4&category=photoshop&author=gashnikov-mv&book=2003&page=67

Comment: Откройте для себя англоязычный интернет: [Image Processing using C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33838/Image-Processing-using-C) , [Adjusting Contrast of an Image in C#](http://www.gutgames.com/post/Adjusting-Contrast-of-an-Image-in-C.aspx)

Comment: Да и в русскоязычном [есть](http://geometry.karazin.ua/resources/documents/20140425155045_3d8d1ed933c3b.pdf), ни когда не занимался подобными темами, но понял что зачем и куда. Правда, боюсь, даже в ультра сжатом виде полноценный ответ потянет на полноценную статью. Может кто-то и возьмется...